# Переключение картинок между двумя button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Подскажите оптимальный способ : нужно по нажатию на первый `button` вывести первую картинку, по нажатию на второй `button` - вывести вторую картинку. 
Когда выводится одна картинка, - другая скрывается.

Пример кода:

```
<div class="box">
  <button class="b1">Push please</button>
  <img class="watermelon" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/food-set-3/91/Food_C246-256.png" alt="">
</div>
<div class="box">
  <button class="b2">Push please</button>
  <img class="apple" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fruits-8/512/apple-256.png" alt="">
</div>


div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}
button {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.apple {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделал универсальный и обновленный вариант на 4 строчки `jQuery`:

```js
$('.box').on('click', '.btn', (e)=> {
    const srcAttr = $(e.target).data('src');
    $('.image').css('background-image', `url(${srcAttr})`);
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
button {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.image-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.image {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <button data-src='https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/food-set-3/91/Food_C246-256.png' class="btn">food</button>
  <button data-src='https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fruits-8/512/apple-256.png' class="btn">fruit</button>

</div>

<div class="image-box">
   <div class="image">
</div>
```

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/9noxb16f/2/) на JSFiddle.

Comment: Крутой вариант, но к сожалению у меня не работает. У меня картинка бекграундом стоит(

Comment: Если приводить пример на твоем ответе - .image-box { background-image: image ; }

Comment: Так вопрос решился или помочь ещё чем-то ?

Comment: Вопрос не решился, вы меняете картинку в img, а у меня задача стоит менять картинки в background-image:...;  :(

Comment: Без проблем сейчас перепишу под твое решение но с тебя отметить ответ как верный^^

Comment: Проверяй, сейчас так как ты хотел?

Comment: Чувак, ты очень крутой. Работает!

Comment: Где можно с тобой в лс пообщаться?

Comment: Незнаю,  но можешь написать в телеграмм @Zicrael

Answer (score 5):

В `JS` noob, кажется не слишком хорошим решением, но всё же вот:

```js
var first = document.getElementById('btn1');
var second = document.getElementById('btn2');
var watermelon = document.getElementsByClassName('watermelon')[0];
var apple = document.getElementsByClassName('apple')[0];

first.onclick = function() {
  apple.classList.add("off");
  watermelon.classList.remove("off");
  watermelon.classList.add("on");
}

second.onclick = function() {
  watermelon.classList.add("off");
  apple.classList.remove("off");
  apple.classList.add("on");
}
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 50px;
}

.on {
  display: block;
}

.off {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <button class="b1" id="btn1">Watermelon</button>
  <button class="b2" id="btn2">Apple</button>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img class="watermelon" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/food-set-3/91/Food_C246-256.png" alt="">
  <img class="apple off" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fruits-8/512/apple-256.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Все равно благодарен тебе за ответ! Начну анализировать. Вообще хотел в jquery реализовать :)

Comment: Сейчас я допишу очень хороший ответ и скину на jQuery) жди)